# Groovy: RedHat: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql:

Tags: mysql, jdbc, groovy, driver, redhat

I tryed to execute groovy-script under RH shell

> [localhost]# groovy /home/rualas4/script.groovy

but received exception

```
Caught: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql:/localhost:3306/
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql:/localhost:3306/
        at script.run(script.groovy:13)
```

I had installed next packages:

```
unixODBC-2.2.14-12.el6_3.x86_64
mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.2-1.el6.x86_64
```

and my code:

```
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader = true)
@Grab(group='mysql', module='mysql-connector-java', version='5.1.25')

import groovy.sql.Sql
import groovy.io.FileType

println "Initialize connection"
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"
username = "test"
password = "test"
driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
sql = Sql.newInstance(url, username, password, driver)
```

also I have *mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar* in my groovy (*/opt/groovy/lib*) directory

Please, provide a solution for resolve error exception

Comment: Can you try removing it from `/opt/groovy/lib`?  Having two similar jars on the same classpath is never a good thing

Comment: Isn't there an error in the URL? Shouldn't it be: `jdbc:mysql://10.242.182.152:3306/<DB_NAME>`? Also `DB_NAME` is missing?

Comment: @Opal: in my code I'm using syntax like that: `sql.eachRow("SELECT * FROM "+name+".TABLE WHERE COLUMN = 'VALUE')`  _name_ is name of database. My program is working under Windows, but not under RH.

Comment: @tim_yates: I removed _mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar_ from _/opt/groovy/lib_ dir and when I execute my script it's freezes in console.. I don't see the result of working of my script, and the only way to interrupt the execution of my script it's break it by CTL+C

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `/` character in your connection url, when `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` parse your url is looking for `jdbc:mysql://`:

`com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` class:

```
package com.mysql.jdbc;

import java.sql.SQLException;

  public class Driver extends NonRegisteringDriver implements java.sql.Driver {
    // ~ Static fields/initializers
    // ---------------------------------------------

    //
    // Register ourselves with the DriverManager
    //
    static {
        try {
            java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver(new Driver());
        } catch (SQLException E) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Can't register driver!");
        }
    }

    // ~ Constructors
    // -----------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Construct a new driver and register it with DriverManager
     * 
     * @throws SQLException
     *             if a database error occurs.
     */
    public Driver() throws SQLException {
        // Required for Class.forName().newInstance()
    }
  }
```

`com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver` class:

```
package com.mysql.jdbc;

import java.sql.SQLException;

public class NonRegisteringDriver implements java.sql.Driver {

    ...

    private static final String URL_PREFIX = "jdbc:mysql://";

    ...
public Properties parseURL(String url, Properties defaults)
            throws java.sql.SQLException {
        Properties urlProps = (defaults != null) ? new Properties(defaults)
                : new Properties();

        if (url == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (!StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(url, URL_PREFIX)
                && !StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(url, MXJ_URL_PREFIX)
                && !StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(url,
                        LOADBALANCE_URL_PREFIX)
                && !StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(url,
                        REPLICATION_URL_PREFIX)) {

            return null;
        }
            ...
 }
```

therefore:

**Change:**

`jdbc:mysql:/localhost:3306/`

**To:**

`jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/`

Hope this helps,

Comment: Still freezes after execute

Comment: Yes, I have. I tryed remove this file and added it again. It doesn't help.